# Ajax.Jquery.Post.sending data to asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

dear friends.I have a problem with ajax.I do not understand how to properly display variable in asp.Please help me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.post(
       "demo_test_post.aspx",
       {
           param1: "para1",
           param2: 2
       },
       onAjaxSuccess
       );

        function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

i use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
thanks

Comment: <body>
 
<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>
<form id="Form1" runat = "server">
    <%
    string a = Request["param1"];
    Response.Write(a);
     %>
</form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button").click(function () {

$.post( "demo_test_post.aspx",{param1: "para1", param2: 2}, function(data) {
   alert(data);
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});

});
});
```

Comment: This conclusion is not working <form id="Form1" runat = "server">
    <%
    string a = Request["param1"];
    Response.Write(a);
     %>
</form> in first alert i see code all page

Comment: Are you including jQuery file?

Comment: yes all code my page `<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {

            $.post("demo_test_post.aspx", { param1: "para1", param2: 2 }, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            })
.done(function () {
    alert("second success");
})
.fail(function () {
    alert("error");
})
.always(function () {
    alert("finished");
});  }); });</script>`

Comment: `</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>
<form id="Form1" runat = "server">
    <%
    string a = Request["param1"];
    Response.Write(a);
     %>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Please post the code in the fiddle, or in the original post.